# Exchange WebService reference not found

Tags: c#, web-services

I have inherited some code that uses Microsoft Exchange Web service but does not compile. 
I downloaded the latest SDK and imported the Microsoft.Echange.WevbService.dll in the project , then referenced it

using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

but the code still does not compile. All classes belonging to this namespace are not resolved and I keep getting errors.

Is there any workaround that?

Answer (score 2):

For SDK v1.2 set Target Framework .NET 3.5 (normal, not "client profile")
For v.2.0 => .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

EWS used to come in two flavors 32 and 64 bit. I surmise the old code was 32....

Here is an article on my blog on getting it to run: [C#: Getting All Emails From Exchange using Exchange Web Services](http://omegacoder.com/?p=454). Unfortunately my link on my blog works, but drops one into a general MS Download area now.